# how to properly handle input dependent async data calls in react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, promise

I am currently building some apps using Typescript and React. To this date i have used some smelly workarounds for the following situation which i would like to get rid of. Maybe you know a better way of doing such.

The Setup:
Having a React Component which sould display data which is fetched from server on user input.
Example use case: fetch the name of a city from an API based on a postal code entered by user.
Example implementation:

```tsx
import * as React from 'react';

export interface IXmplState {
  plc: string;
  name: string;
}

export default class Xmpl extends React.Component<{}, IXmplState> {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {name: "", plc: ""};
  }

  private fetchName(plc: string): Promise<string> {
    //Fetch data from server.
  }

  private updateName(plc: string): void {
    this.fetchName(plc).then(newName => this.setState({name: newName}));
  }

  public render(): React.ReactElement<{}> {
    return(
      <div>
        <input value={this.state.plc} onChange={(event) => this.updateName(event.target.value)}/>
        <div>{this.state.name}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

The problem:
As soon as the user input changes, the `updateName()` is called, which then updates the `state` on resolved promise. Consider the following case:

1. The input is changed and a an update promise (A) is created and now pending.
2. The input is changed again and a new update promise (B) is created.
3. Promise B is resolved while promise A is still pending.
4. The state will now be changed to the result of promise B.
5. Promise A is now resolved and will override the result of Promise B in the state.
6. The user is now presented with the wrong name (schould be result of B but is result of A)

Are there ways to surpress such behavior? Are there specific ways/libs for doing this in React, typescript or javascript? Or is such kind of input handling generally to be avoided? Which would be a better way or the best way of handling such scenario in gernerally?

Greets and Thanks

EDIT: for the sake of completeness.

My current way of handling such scenarios is introducing a checksum in the component and only update the state if the checksum is still not altered.

```
export default class Xmpl extends React.Component<{}, IXmplState> {
  let nameCkSm: number = 0;
  ...
  private updateName(plc: string): void {
    let ckSm = ++this.nameCkSm;
    this.fetchName(plc).then(newName => this.setState(() => {
      if(this.nameCkSm === ckSm) return {name: newName};
    }));
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`AbortController`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController) (standard web feature, not a lib) is good for this, see `***` comments:

```
export default class Xmpl extends React.Component<{}, IXmplState> {
    // *** An AbortController for the update
    pendingNameController: AbortController | null = null;

    constructor(props: IXmplState) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { name: "", plc: "" };
    }

    // *** Accept the signal
    private fetchName(plc: string, signal?: AbortSignal): Promise<string> {
        // Fetch data from server, pass `signal` if the mechanism supports
        // it (`fetch` and `axios` do, for instance)
    }

    private updateName(plc: string): void {
        // *** Cancel any outstanding call
        this.pendingNameController?.abort();
        // *** Get a controller for this call, and its signal
        this.pendingNameController = new AbortController();
        const { signal } = this.pendingNameController;
        // *** Pass the signal to the `fetchName` method
        this.fetchName(plc, signal)
        .then((name) => {
            // *** Don't update if the request was cancelled (ideally you'd
            // never get here because a cancelled request won't fulfill the
            // promise, but race conditions can mean you would)
            if (!signal.aborted) {
                this.setState({ name });
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            // ...handle.report error...
        })
    }

    public render(): React.ReactElement<{}> {
        // ...
    }
}
```

You can write a utility that handles multiple outstanding requests for different things by wrapping the fetching method, etc. But that's the basic mechanism for using `AbortController` for this.

Answer (score 1):

Your biggest enemy here is the network request and the fact that some take longer than others - resulting in race conditions in which things are happening out of order.

The most important thing you need to do is to abort the previous request and let the "latest" one take precedence. This is done with the help of an [AbortController](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController).

I know you probably won't like this, but I highly advise you move to functional components and hooks. The reason I say this is because it's much easier to organize your code for the different things which are going on, which will make it easier to prevent the race condition. In particular, the `useEffect` hook has a mechanism for cancelling the previous effect... in this case your API request. Here's what it would look like (not tested, but it should be very close):

```
// This is a hook whose only purpose is to make an http request any time the searchQuery changes.
// It takes care of cancelling the previous request
const useSearchRequest = (searchQuery) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({ isLoading: false, error: null, result: null });

    useEffect(() => {
        if (searchQuery) {
            // update the state to show we are loading
            setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, isLoading: true }));
    
            try {
                // create the abort controller and pass the signal to the request
                const controller = new AbortController();
                fetch(`/search?query=${searchQuery}`, { signal: controller.signal })
                .then(req => req.json())
                .then(result => {
                    // update the state with the results
                    setState({ isLoading: false, error: null, result });
                });
            } catch(error) {
                // update the state with the error
                setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, isLoading: false, error }));
            }
    
            // any time searchQuery changes, this method will be called and will cancel the previous request
            return () => controller.abort();
        }
    // this tells the effect to rerun every time searchQuery changes
    }, [searchQuery]);

    return state;
}

const Xmpl = () => {
    const [searchVal, setSearchVal] = useState('');
    const { isLoading, error, result } = useSearchRequest(searchVal);

    return(
        <div>
          {isLoading ? 'loading...' : null}
          {error ? `There was an error: ${err}` : null}
          <input value={searchVal} onChange={(event) => setSearchVal(event.target.value)}/>
          <div>{result}</div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've stumbeled across `useEffect` but i could not think of the specific use case in this scenario. Is the `useSearchRequest` called automatically upon `setSearchVal`?

Comment: @Mindxxxd - `useEffect` isn't relevant to your code, you're writing a `class` component, and hooks are only relevant to function components.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, but i am not bound to class components. If a function component will handle these scenarios better, i may use them.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I explain in my answer that switching to a functional component will make this problem easier to solve thanks to better code organization.

Comment: @Mindxxxd - yes, every time you call a state setter (`setSearchVal`), it will cause a rerender. For functional components, this just means that the function is called again - in which case the updated `searchVal` will be passed to the `useSearchRequest` hook. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @RyanWheale - Due respect, but that's opinion, not fact. It's perfectly straightfoward to handle this in `class` components too, and many people find `class` components *easier* to organize and understand, not harder. Each (function components and `class` components) have their trade-offs. (I'm fairly neutral on them.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - thanks for the response, and due respect as well - but I can hardly make sense of the class implementation. You have all the behavior for a single feature spread out between different properties and methods, and you're not even handing the different states of an http request. Add those in and you have a real mess - and I don't consider that an opinion. Whereas the functional/hook pattern wraps all the behavior and state into a single function with a single parameter which can be easily tested and reused across the app. I don't see the "trade off".

Comment: @RyanWheale - That's not an accurate description at all. Two. Two places in the code: Where it's declared, and where it's used. That's not "all over." The other is just that you did that and I didn't bother. It can easily be tweaked to do that. But when I said "trade off," I wasn't talking about these implementations, I was talking about `class` vs. function components. There's no question that there's a trade-off involved there, and that it being "much easier" is clearly a matter of opinion. I'm going to leave it at that, I suspect we won't agree, and that's fine. Happy coding.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - not sure why we are having this discussion here, but a single property is declared at the top of your class, it's given a value much further down in the class, and the value is passed to another function where it is finally consumed. This is all mixed in with the search box state and change handler, and it doesn't even address the state around the http request. You are conflating "much easier" with "more familiar", which are not the same thing. I get that classes are a safe place for people, but they are in fact not easier or better or equivalent - more of an abomination to JS.